# Are there any other Indian superheroes in the Marvel universe?

Tags: marvel, comics, super-hero

I know about Dinesh Deol, aka Grid, who is an Inhuman.

Are there any other Indian superheroes in an *ongoing* Marvel comic series?

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Indians

Answer (score 10):

As [@Valorum](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum) pointed out in comments, there are lots of Indian characters in Marvel. Here's the list: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Indians

Also, worth pointing out: Indian gods [Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh (Shiva)](http://hindudeity.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Brahma-vishnu-Mahesh6-1.jpg) and Indra have appeared in Marvel comics. [Thor even defeated Shiva](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/158366/1) in *Thor #301*.

[image]

In another issue:

[image]

**Note:** Depictions of gods would look funny to someone who is familiar with those gods in modern Indian media (TV etc), but Marvel's version can't be wrong as they include all the signature features provided by religious texts viz. 4 heads of Bramha, 3 eyes of Shiva.

**Update:**
As I see you are looking for Indian "superheroes" in Marvel, here's the list:

- [Spider-Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Pavitr_Prabhakar_(Earth-50101))
- [Ghost Rider](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Shoba_Mirza_(Earth-616))
- [Agni, Lord of Fire](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Araman_Nila_(Earth-616))
- [Grid](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Dinesh_Deol_(Earth-616))
- Hindu Gods: Ganesha ([Earth-41001](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ganesha_(Earth-41001)); [Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ganesha_(Earth-616))), [Lakshmi](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Lakshmi_(Earth-41001)), [Skanda](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Skanda_(Earth-41001))
- Triad Brothers: [Jonathan Tremont](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_Tremont_(Earth-616)), [Lord Templar](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_Templar_(Tremont)_(Earth-616)), [Pagan](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Pagan_(Earth-616))
- Omega Sentinel ([Earth-12131](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Karima_Shapandar_(Earth-12131)); [Earth-41001](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Karima_Shapandar_(Earth-41001)); [Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Karima_Shapandar_(Earth-616)))
- [Thunderbird](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Neal_Shaara_(Earth-616))
- [Indra](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Paras_Gavaskar_(Earth-616))
- [Vesper](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Raani_Jatwinder_(Earth-616))
- [Timeslip](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Rina_Patel_(Earth-616))
- [Sapna](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sapna_(Earth-616))
- [Sati](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sati_(Earth-41001))
- [Cerebra / Ice Queen](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Shakti_Haddad_(Earth-928))
- [Brahman](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Vivatma_Visvajit_(Earth-616))
- [Tigerman](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Tigerman_(Earth-616))
- [Taboo](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Taboo_(Earth-616))
- Dr. Kavita Rao ([Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kavita_Rao_(Earth-616)); [Earth-11326](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kavita_Rao_(Earth-11326)); [Earth-TRN338](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kavita_Rao_(Earth-TRN338)))

Super Villains:

- [Black Fog](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Fog_(Earth-616))
- [Star Thief](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ditmal_Pirvat_(Earth-616))
- [Doctor Octopus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Octopus_(Earth-50101))
- [Black Box](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Garabed_Bashur_(Earth-616))
- [Zero/One](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Parul_Kurinji_(Earth-616))
- Vindaloo ([Earth-2149](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Venkat_Katregadda_(Earth-2149)); [Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Venkat_Katregadda_(Earth-616)))
- [Kludge](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kludge_(Earth-616))

Other super-powered individuals:

- [Ghazandi](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ghazandi_(Earth-616))
- [Calculus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Jahaharel_Patel_(Earth-616))

Comment: I've made a small edit to fix little things but mostly to bump your post back up after Mr. Valorum got a bit excited with tag edits, hope you don't mind!

Comment: Are any of these *superheroes*?

Comment: I removed the comic panels from your answer - I felt that they occupied too much space for the little information they gave.

Comment: Are any of them *current*?

Comment: @Valorum - Speaking of tag edits *en masse*, although they may be necessary housekeeping from time to time (which I can appreciate), is there a way of not having them all jump to the top of the feed all at once when doing this? One of the things I love about this site is the variety of subjects covered. I personally find it kind of boring to see 50 Star Wars or Harry Potter posts all crammed at the top of the feed all of a sudden.

Comment: @iMerchant - I'm nearly done. i've been trying to space them out over the course of a week and got a bit enthusiastic this afternoon.

Comment: Could somebody mention the ongoing series...as I have said I know grid that's it

Comment: These seem like minor characters (which still fills the question's requirements). Have any of these had their own comic, or been a member of a team that had its own comic?

Comment: @DCShannon Thunderbird was a member of the Avengers, at least during Operation Galactic Storm. Spider-man India had his own comic (2004-05).

Answer (score 3):

**10 Indian Superheroes in Marvel Comics**

[image: Indian superheroes banner]

1. Indra

Though he religiously believes in absolute non-violence, he is later imposed to act in self-defense and attack a corrupt military officer, that cause in an internal struggle and resulting him to lose access to all his powers.
2. Thunderbird

3. Vesper
4. Grid
5. Spider-Man: India
6. Sati
7. Timeslip
8. Brahman
9. Cerebra
10. Tigerman

The origin of the tangled vegetation hero known as Tigerman. He has a faithful companion an ape named Rangoo, the only one to better know the Tigerman.

Main Source: [10 Indian Superheroes in Marvel Comic Universe](http://www.muvibuff.com/10-indian-superheroes-in-marvel-comics/)