# Are there any Indian superheroes in DC?

Tags: dc

Marvel comics has a lot of Indian [superheroes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158364/are-there-any-other-indian-superheroes-in-the-marvel-universe), but are there any in the DC comics universe?

Comment: Downvoting due to lack of basic research. I simply googled Indian DC characters and got this very first link: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Indians

Comment: VTC as an open-ended list question.

Answer (score 1):

Heroes:

**Solstice** (Kiran Singh [New Earth](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kiran_Singh_(New_Earth)) & [Earth Prime](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kiran_Singh_(Prime_Earth)))) is a member of the Teen Titens

[**Celsius**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Arani_Desai_(New_Earth))  (Arani Desai New Earth) a member of the Doom Patrol

[**The Green**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Levi_Kamei_(Prime_Earth)) (One of his avatars at least is Levi Kamei in Prime Earth)

[**Randu Singh**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Randu_Singh_(New_Earth)) (New Earth)

[**Aruna Shende**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Aruna_Shende_(New_Earth)) (New Earth)

Villians:

**[White Rabbit](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jaina_Hudson_(Prime_Earth))** (Jaina Hudson Earth Prime) American with an Indian mother

[**Jinx**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jinx_(New_Earth)) (New Earth a villain without a real name)

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, [Rama Kushna](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/rama-kushna/4005-12158/) appears (based on name and mode of dress, as well as the limited background I found) to be from northern India or Tibet.  She is the goddess responsible for the creation of Deadman (formerly Boston Brand).  There may be others; based on the age of DC and the common biases present in older comics, I looked for "mystic" characters, which search brought up everyone who uses magic or exists because of magic.